# I have a navigation bar that becomes fixed at the top after scrolling 1 full page. After scrolling halfway, it skips the rest of the page

Tags: javascript, css

Full code: http://liveweave.com/XGPWVt

I "inspected" it with chrome, and it happens when the #header_nav goes from relative to fixed. I tried changing the third line to `if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.bottom) {` but then the navigation bar doesn't ever get fixed at the top.

```
var elementPosition = $('#header_nav').offset();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
    $('#header_nav').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
  } else {
    $('#header_nav').css('position','relative');
  }
});
```

This only happens when I make the preview window FULLSCREEN.

It also doesn't happen when I set the header heights to px values. But I need them as percentages for scaling.

Comment: I was on your link, but that code is something else.
You can always add a transition:.5s or so to smooth out and "animate" the transition from fixed to relative.
This is of course not the best solution, we need to see the full code first.

Comment: @damianocelent how about this: http://liveweave.com/hKqrkR

Comment: I am working on it:-) 
This is very hard, am on my 4th solution attempt already.

Comment: Ah, position property cannot be animated. I have run out of ideas for now, will check tomorrow again. I have checked some other examples and nobody has done it any smoother than yours is. Even the treehouse guy Guil H. couldn't come up with any better.
Have a look at this, its not the same but you will see what i mean:
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/adbzGX
If i were you, I would do it like that, as it's even pure JS, no library.

Comment: @damianocelent hmm... Is there a way to set the header and background-image heights with px, and make them scale to the width of the screen (not using a percentage, which is causing the problem)?

Comment: Well, you can leave the width set at 100% and set height to px, add background-image properties for the pic like this:
background-size:100% 100%; background-repeat:no-repeat;
I have tried to set the height in 100vh etc, but all does not help.
Btw it happens all the same on small screen too, it's just less obvious, but the pic jumps some 30% in height.
I have some better layouts in mind, I think the fixed pos on scroll is no good choice. I'd fade out the pic and scale + translate the nav on scroll.